# Where does UIWebView saves the WebDB database?

Tags: ios, html, uiwebview, web-sql

I'm developing an iOS app which uses a UIWebView and the WebApp running inside uses WebDB to store it's local data.

I would like to 'reset' the state of the my which would include:

1. Removing any cached items (images, html and etc) - This is done and is working fine :-)
2. Remove any WebDB created by the Webapp.

Anyone has any ideias on how to do item n. 2?

Answer (score 2):

The only answer I have ever found was re-installing the app. That definitely works. Clearing Safari's cache under Settings does not. There is a way to do this in Android, but not iOS.

You know webdb is deprecated, right? I wouldn't recommend building a new app on it. IndexDB is the replacement, and it works fine in a UIWebView. You'll have the same issues with clearing it, though.

If you can, implement an application-side clearing routine and do it yourself. During development, I like to implement a "hidden" 5-pixel spot somewhere that does this when tapped, then reloads the view when tapped. It makes development MUCH faster. You can even leave it there during the Beta phase if it's not a security risk, or have the server render it only to users based on credentials.